# Is this error selection or conditional? (Java)

Tags: java, if-statement, input, range, selection

I have an error, on the third IF statement. It checks to see if the user entered at number within a range (1-6) and the letter is a-f. I cant test my search algorithm because there seems to be an error in that line. I can't work it out. What seems to be wrong? Is it the answer.charAt(1)?

```
boolean wronganswer = true;
while (wronganswer == true){

    answer = (String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, new JLabel(sb.toString()), "Battleships", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, pic, null, "");
    if(answer.length() == 2){
        if ((Character.isLetter(answer.charAt(0))) && (Character.isDigit(answer.charAt(1)))){
            if ((answer.charAt(1) >= 0) && (answer.charAt(1) <= 6)){
                for (int k = 0; k < rows.length; k++){
                    if(rows[k] == (""+answer.charAt(0))){
                        wronganswer=false;
                    }
                }
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"No! That letter is not on the grid!");
            }
            else{
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"No! That number is not on the grid!");
                System.out.println(answer.charAt(1));
            }
        }
        else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"No! Enter a letter, THEN a number!");
        }
    }
    else{
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"No! Enter ONE letter and ONE number!");
    }

}
```

[EDIT] Fixed an indentation error when pasting to stack overflow

Comment: `charAt(1) `returns the character, not the number that a digit represents: `(answer.charAt(1) >= '0') ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your code:

```
if ((answer.charAt(1) >= 0) && (answer.charAt(1) <= 6)){
```

You get a `char`. Even if your character is a digit, its value is its [ASCII value](http://www.asciitable.com/).

So your condition actually doesn't test if you input a digit between 0 and 6 but it tests if you character is either NUL, SOH, STX, ETX, EOT, ENQ or ACK.

If you want to check if you char is a digit in a range, you have to add single quote around your range limit numbers:

```
if ((answer.charAt(1) >= '0') && (answer.charAt(1) <= '6')){
```

Or replace the limits with their ASCII value:

```
if ((answer.charAt(1) >= 48) && (answer.charAt(1) <= 54)){
```

Comment: This fixed the error! Thank you! Then I got the "letter not on grid" error. But I fixed it by Bathsheba's response, so I will give you the correct answer because you answered the question in the titel

Answer (score 2):

This is due to `==` comparing a reference with an anonymous temporary `java.lang.String`, which will always be `false`. The fix is simple; use

`rows[k].equals("" + answer.charAt(0));`

instead, which compares the string *contents*. You could use the flashier *Yoda Expression*

`("" + answer.charAt(0)).equals(rows[k])`

which will not throw a `NullPointerException` if `rows[k]` is `null`.

Comment: Thank you! I will change that. However, I mean the line comparing the range (I think I explained my question wrongly). For example, the number entered is a3, and it says "That number is not on the grid!" When it is in range. Even when I write a9 it does the same!

Comment: Fixed! Thanks again